# How to use snowball (.sbl) file in Python

Tags: python, nltk, snowball

I am a first-year Master's student currently learning NLP with Python. My professor has assigned me a mini project that involves implementing Porter Stemmer in Snowball Language. However, I am a bit confused and would appreciate some assistance from anyone experienced with Snowball (.sbl).

Specifically, I would like to know how to compile these files. If anyone could help me, I would be grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read the page [Using Snowball](https://snowballstem.org/runtime/use.html) on the Snowball website?

Comment: I tried, but I could understand it correctly, Is Snowball is compiling only in Linux ?, if so then I'll switch to Linux because I am using Windows 11.

Comment: I have installed make, but when open the folder and run 'make' command in the folder it returns an error.

Comment: Yes.  I looked at the source code, and it is clearly designed for Unix-like systems.  It should work on Linux or MacOS, or in the WSL subsystem of Windows.